# Get multiple objects of reverse foreign_key relation inside values()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have two django models as below:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()


class Entry(models.Model):
    entry_id = models.Autofield(primary_key=True)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog')
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    mod_date = models.DateField()
```

I'm trying to get the backward relation using related_name. I want to get the entire data of the 'Entry' by using related_name 'blog'.

There are multiple entry's for each blog.

**How can I achieve the following output:**

```
{'name': '', 'tagline': '', 'all_blogs':[{'blog': '','headline': '','body_text': '','pub_date': '', 'mod_date': ''},]}
```

I tried this:

```
response = Blog.objects.filter(
            name=name,
            blog__pub_date=date
        ).values(
            'name',
            'tagline',
            all_blogs=Entry.objects.filter(entry_id=F(blog__entry_id)).values()
        )
        return response
```

But it is throwing field error saying I cannot use "blog" field inside F() expression.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: I think it's poor practice to give a related_name that is identical (aside from capitalization) to the name of one of your models (Blog and blog), and this might even be what is causing problems for you. Even if it's not the cause, this sort of naming leads to a lot of ambiguity in your code. Furthermore, the line: all_blogs=Entry.objects.filter(...) doesn't make sense: querying on the Entry table will return Entry objects, not Blog objects, so why are you assigning the results to key a named 'all_blogs" ?

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that by giving the ForeignKey from `Entry` to `Blog` a related name *blog*, might give you a slight headache later on. I'm not sure if my answers even work properly because of this. It could be easier to use related_name *entry* instead.

**I try to give working examples anyway.** 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg 
(`Edit:` If you would be using **psql**.) With an ArrayAgg you have an option to get a list of multiple foreign keys pointing to this current entry. This will give you a list of related `Entry` ids *which is not exactly what you wanted*. But this is a fairly simple Django query solution to get you started with the result format you want.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg


response = Blog.objects.filter(
            name=name,
            blog__pub_date=date
        ).annotate(
            all_blogs=ArrayAgg('blog')
        ).values(
            'name',
            'tagline',
            'all_blogs'
        )
return response
```

**Pythonish way** 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related 
Less of an Django query and sql based and more of a Python oriented solution that actually *gives you the data structure and all the information you wanted*. Could be by looping the queryset you have at hand and by creating the list of dictionaries on the go.

With this solution you of course have all the power to format the response structure freely. 
`Note!` Python loops are not nearly as efficient as formulating the data by SQL so you need to consider if it is an option you can use.

```
queryset = Blog.objects.filter(
    name=name,
    blog__pub_date=date
).prefetch_related(
    'blog_set'
)

response = [
    {
        'name': blog.name, 
        'tagline': blog.tagline, 
        'all_blogs': blog.blog_set.all().values()
    } for blog in queryset
]

return response
```

`Edit:` Clarification on database query count
With prefetch_related it is possible to JOIN reversed ForeignKeys or ManyToMany fields to the original queryset. Under the hood this is done with python and not with sql. This means that we are hitting the database twice:

- once for the original query
- once for the related query that is then "joined" to the original queryset with python

After that we are not making more queries to the database in our loop.

Here is an excellent explanation on how *prefetch_related* works (and select_related): 
https://medium.com/better-programming/django-select-related-and-prefetch-related-f23043fd635d

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I am using mysql as backend. So, first option is not suitable.
Regarding the 2nd option, I am confused about the number of times the db gets hit. Will it be once or will it hit every time inside loop?

Comment: @Manohar : With prefetch_related we are hitting the database twice.

Once for the Blog objects and second for the Entry objects (related_name blog). This "joining" is built with python and not by sql, this is why there is two separate queries to database. The loop itself won't be hitting the database anymore.